# Публикация решений задач с платформ типа LeetCode

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, самоответы

У меня появилась идея собрать на ruSO задачи из разных платформ типа `LeetCode`, `Яндекс Контест`, `Codewars` и т.д. и дать на них наши ответы и пояснения

Да, я понимаю что на них можно найти ответы либо на самих платформах либо в интернете, у тех кто опубликовал решения. На том же GitHub есть много людей, кто уже собрал или начинал собирать ответы на задачи из `LeetCode`. Пример таких репозиториев:

- [kamyu104/LeetCode-Solutions](https://github.com/kamyu104/LeetCode-Solutions)
- [haoel/leetcode](https://github.com/haoel/leetcode)
- [neetcode-gh/leetcode](https://github.com/neetcode-gh/leetcode)

Или на ютубе много таких каналов, например:

- [LeetCode Solutions](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU_sdQYzUj2keVENTP0a5rdykRSgg9Wp-)
- [Leetcode BLIND-75 Solutions](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLot-Xpze53ldVwtstag2TL4HQhAnC8ATf)

Но почти везде объяснения и решения на английском. Потому как мне кажется, было бы здорово у нас тут собрать решения на разных языках программирования и давать разъяснения именно на русском языке. Можно договориться чтобы в таких вопросах не было принятых ответов

Тут на самом деле много чего ещё стоит обсудить (оформление, теги, дубликаты и т.д.), но мне просто интересно мнение нашего общества. Более детально обсуждать можно будет в серии других вопросов, если вам в целом идея покажется привлекательной

Видите ли вы пользу в этом? Может вам так же как и мне кажется что это полезно для **базы знаний** т.к. будут обсуждаться очень много алгоритмов? и т.д.

Жду ваших в комментариев и ответов :)

Comment: Но таким образом мы будем давать самоответы на вопросы-домашки! Нет, я хочу сохранить карму чистой.

Comment: А правила этих площадок что говорят насчет размещения их задач на сторонних ресурсах? Если правила запрещают копирование, это действительно будет плагиатом.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Не читал, но увидя в интернете очень много всего этого на английском, подумал почему бы нам не сделать то же самое на русском. Потому что мне бывало трудно на русском находить хорошее объяснение того или иного алгоритма, и приходилось читать/слушать на английском. Вот и подумал, что было бы неплохо с очень опытными людьми вместе сделать свою базу по алгоритмам

Comment: @EzioMercer всё же *"база по алгоритмам"* и *"база решений задачек с площадок"*, это достаточно разные вещи.

Comment: @Kromster Но эти алгоритмы все рассматриваются в рамках задачи. Просто голые описания алгоритмов не знаю насколько полезны. Такие вещи обычно пишут в википедии. Я думал что будет намного лучше помимо описания самого алгоритма показать как она работает в той или иной задаче. Как в универе например, лекция идёт, а потом по ней задачи делают (просто в этом случае была бы 1 задача)

Comment: @Kromster Вернее даже не совсем так. Вот у нас в универе бывало такое, что нам дают задачу, мы ломаем голову, а потом нам говорят, что вот та теорема тут применима. Или например показывали как можно решить эту задачу разными способами. Вот и мы например могли бы к одной задаче давать несколько решений например у одного алгоритма было время `O(n^2)` и память `O(1)`, а у другого время `O(n)` и память `O(n)`. В комментариях можно было бы обсуждать какой где применять и т.д.

Comment: @EzioMercer важно разделять, что ruSO заточен на составление Базы Знаний по практическим задачам, а не на тренировку скиллов. ЛитКод (и прочие) же как раз наоборот - на тренировку. Если вам не хватает пояснений/обсуждений к решаемым там задачкам - искать их надо там же (например на ЛитКоде эти разделы есть). Заметьте, что в Вики почему-то тоже, присутствуют алгоритмы с описаниями, но отсутствуют тренировочные задачки. Каждая платформа отвечает за свое.

Comment: @Kromster Ну там тоже 99% обсуждений на английском... На счёт "Базы Знаний по практическим задачам" - это где-то прописано или просто так повелось? Ну и как по мне почти любой алгоритм применим в какой-то практической задаче :)

Comment: @EzioMercer вы говорите о разном. То что где-то что-то на английском есть, не значит, что это надо на ruSO тащить. Пример, "есть книга вопросов по DnD, на английском. Давайте её переводить и на ruSO складывать?" - нет, не давайте. Во главе угла - соответствие тематике. Где прописано - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour. При этом, мне ваша идея вполне нравится, но её реализации стоит быть вне ruSO.

Comment: @Kromster Не считаю что пример корректен. Потому что это про игру, но если бы это были бы вопросы про программирование, то я не вижу проблем с тем чтобы на ruSO были те же вопросы на русском :) Но я знаю что мне будет лень одному этим заниматься ну или выдохнусь через время, потому хотел чтобы с участниками ruSO вместе (так веселее) сделали бы что-то такое и ruSO показалось отличным местом для этого :)

Comment: @EzioMercer пример специально гиперболизирован. Читайте выше - задачки на enSO/ruSO оффтоп. При должной обработке - да, становятся онтопом, только вот при должной обработке от задачи ничего не останется, а будут "Просто голые описания алгоритмов", которые вам не нравятся )

Comment: @Kromster Ладно, убедили :) Но вы сказали что идея вам нравится, где бы вы предложили такое сделать?

Comment: Если на Github их выкладывают, почему бы там же и не выкладывать на русском? Русский язык на Github не запрещен. Можно прорекламировать репозиторий где-нибудь у нас в чатах, чтобы люди о нем узнали.

Comment: @EzioMercer вижу несколько аспектов - контент (генерация + хранение), интерфейс (создателям + читателям), хостинг, пиар. Навскидку кажется, что подошел бы какой-то опен-сорсный клон SO, а для начала и просто форум с правилами и модерацией. Самое сложное - пиар )

Comment: Всё таки интересно, как радикально иначе голосуют на вопросы, объявленные дубликатами.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ если вы о голосах на этот вопрос и на назначенный дубликат - они не так сильно одинаковы ;-) *плюс 6 лет прошло, плюс кто-то может минус поставить за то что ТС не поискал "дубликата" перед тем как спросить

Comment: @Kromster ага, и ещё нас уверяют, что дубликаты это хорошо, помогают приходить из поисковиков и бла-бла-бла... а потом минусуют.

Comment: Не пойму зачем вы все в одну кучу мешаете. В общих чертах, владельцы SO опробовали этот функционал и решили оставить. Если у вас есть сомнения в его пользе - стоит поднять вопрос на MSE и быть готовым, к тому что ответ будет "don't fix it if it ain't broken"

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight А на GitHub можно создавать проект, который будет принадлежать не одному человеку, а сразу группе пользователей?

Comment: @EzioMercer да, конечно. Делайте организацию. Только все равно у кого-то из них будет прав больше (например, на удаление репозитория)

Comment: @EzioMercer Не только можно, но и часто практикуется: https://docs.github.com/ru/organizations

Comment: Спасибо вам обоим, если начну что-то такое делать, то обязательно дам знать :) Что вам кажется более эффективным: начать писать сайт на подобие форума и хостить, например на том же GitHub Pages или чтобы репозиторий сам был бы набором лекций и примеров кода?

Comment: Я бы начал с макета (хоть в тетради) и обкатки на нем десятка сценариев того, что людям там должно было бы быть интересно. Потом обрезать скучную половину и посмотреть что в остатке и на чем этот MVP (minimal viable product) можно запилить с вашими скилами. А может и просто сделать клона  с успешного аналога (как ruSO создавался)

Comment: @Kromster Значит вы за сайт :)

Comment: Я за то чтобы у вас получилось, а как - это детали ) (посмотрите https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/are-there-any-clones-alternatives-for-running-a-stack-exchange-style-qa-site)

Comment: Возьмите за пример проекты по вашим ссылкам. Для начала можно просто публиковать решения в репозитории. Затем, если возникнет необходимость, прикрутить скрипт, который будет генерировать не основе них сайт. Форум вы не сможете сделать на Github Pages, это хостинг только для статических сайтов.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Не очень понял что вы имеете ввиду под статическим сайтом, но я там запускал React приложение с логином и всё работало

Comment: Статический сайт - это когда есть только HTML+JS+CSS, без серверной части (БД, сервисы). Можно выложить UI на React, но для работы серверной части понадобится другой хостинг, который это поддерживает.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight А, я там подключил FireBase и всё работало хорошо. Не знаю что там происходит при больших нагрузках, но если дойдёт до такого что будут нагрузки прям больие, то мы вместе (ruSO) что-то придумаем :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если решение задачи взято с других ресурсов, то публикация такого решения — это плагиат. Плагиат здесь не приветствуется.

Допустимый сценарий, это когда участник либо решает задачу, либо решил, и задал здесь вопрос, а отвечающий либо помогает с решением возникшей у автора вопроса конкретной проблемы, либо проводит код-ревью.

Других рабочих сценариев не вижу.

Comment: Почему плагиат то? У нас разве не собственная база знаний? Мы же когда копируем выдержки из документации, не считаем это плагиатом. Да и это не важно, моя цель не просто дать рабочий код, а именно разбор алгоритмов на русском

Comment: @EzioMercer у нас даже есть причина закрытия вопросов _"Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу"_, которая также намекает, что у нас не такой формат базы, который вы предлагаете. Задача сама по себе не может являться вопросом. Вопросом может являться её неполное или неверное решение с обозначением сути проблемы.

Comment: Из твоего ответа не совсем очевидно: публикация задачи - плагиат, или публикация решения?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ _"Публикация решений задач"_ - вполне всё однозначно.

Comment: Я, конечно, не лингвист (но это даже хорошо в данном случае), но к чему относится *"взятых с других ресурсов"* не вполне однозначно (для меня) в текущей формулировке. Последующие предложения добавляют контекста, но, возможно, что в таком случае отвечают не совсем о том, что спрашивает ТС.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ я не против, если поможешь улучшить ответ. :) отредактируй. Просто как по мне, так понятно. Я как бы и не планировал формулировать в юридической форме его.

Comment: @aepot, а публикация решения со стороннего ресурса в ответе (на вопрос, где у автора появились затруднения) это тоже плагиат и не приветствуется здесь? Если да, то куча существующих ответов будут таким плагиатом

Comment: @avp ну, цитирование документации - это не плагиат. А вот например, если ты взял текст и вставил его "как есть" с другого сайта, то это нездоровая история. Например, взял задачу с литкода и ее решение, перевел задачу в вопрос, а решение в ответ - это будет плагиат. А вот если попался конкретный вопрос по проблеме решения этой задачи, а ты ответил на вопрос и пусть даже воспользовался для этого кодом из готового решения, то это уже допустимо. Но экспертам обычно к готовым решениям обращаться не требуется.

Comment: @aepot, я имел в виду код и описание алгоритмов (ну, к примеру, сортировка слиянием. Много ли тут не скопипасченного кода в ответах?)

Comment: @avp это уже не предметный разговор. Если у меня не получилось донести мысль, извините.

Comment: @aepot, наверное мне тоже не удалось донести простую мысль -- надо поменьше администрировать и обращать внимание на всяякие плагиаты. Нужно просто помогать конкретным людям

Comment: @avp Если следовать этой простой мысли, можно нарваться на проблемы, когда жертвы плагиата пойдут жаловаться, и вопросы придется удалять. В проектах по ссылке есть примечание `Since free questions may be even mistakenly taken down by some companies, only solutions will be post on now.`, что как бы тонко намекает именно на это.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, странная фраза `"Since free questions ... only solutions will  be post on now"`, неужели к ответам с плагиатом это не относится?

Comment: @avp Ответ принадлежит тому, кто ответил, а текст задачи - автору задачи или сайту, на котором она опубликована. Поэтому да, проблема плагиата относится именно к задаче, а не к ответу.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, и как это соотносится с утверждением в начале данного ответа -- `"Если решение задачи взято с других ресурсов, то публикация такого решения — это плагиат."`?

Comment: @avp вы про ранзное говорите :)

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, странная позиция -- тут (в тексте вопроса) мы плагиат преследуем, а вот рядом (в тексте ответа)-- уже нет.

Comment: @avp Как мне кажется, такие правила ввели потому что (опять таки наверное) придумать одинаковые решения можно независимо друг от друга с большей вероятностью, чем придумать точь в точь одинаковые задачи независимо друг от друга. Опять таки просто догадки :)

Comment: @EzioMercer, скорее тут правая рука не ведает, что делает левая